# Why reduce function asking for arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I have written these lines of code with reduce built in function but it show an error for given arguments.

### **Error**:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 
      5 lst = [1,2,3]
----> 6 reduce(d_n, lst)

TypeError: d_n() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
from functools import reduce
def d_n(digit):
    return(digit)

lst = [1,2,3]
reduce(d_n, lst)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reduce(...)
    reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

    Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
    from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
    For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
    ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
    of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
    sequence is empty.
```

Key point: *a function of **two** arguments*

Your `d_n()` function takes only one argument, which makes it incompatible with `reduce`